# Difference between print(dir()) and dir()

Tags: python

In Python's interactive shell, executing `dir()` prints a list of names. But in a script `dir()` doesn't provide any output directly, I have to use `print(dir())`.

It is not just `dir()`, other built-in functions behave in the same way.

Is the shell executing those functions in some special way? Is it wrapping those functions in some other function implicitly?

Comment: The python interactive shell prints the return value of functions automatically. In order to see the return value from a script, you must have a `print` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interactive shell is an example of a more general concept called a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), which stands for:

- **R**ead
- **E**valuate
- **P**rint
- **L**oop

The ***P*** above is the difference between the interactive shell and a regular script. The shell is calling `print` for you.

Comment: In particular, the Python shell prints all values except `None`. It's a bit like it runs an implicit `if _ is not None: print(repr(_))` after each input.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not at all specific to the `dir` built-in.

When running code in the Python shell, the result of each statement that is not of `NoneType` is echoed back to the shell, i.e. printed. See for example the following.

```
>>> 2 + 3
5
>>> 2 + 3; 2 + 6
5
8
```

When doing something like `print(2 + 3)`, you are using the built-in to display to your terminal (or wherever your output stream is) the result of `2 + 3`, and `print` then returns a `None` value, which does not get printed out. You can override this by manually printing out whatever `print` returns.

```
>>> print(2 + 3)
5
>>> print(print(2 + 3))
5
None
```

This works the same for any statement.

Now, when you are executing a file directly (not through the REPL shell) it circumvents the step of piping the output of each statement to the standard output. Hence, executing `dir` (or any other function) in a file will not print out its result unless you explicitly tell it to, through `print` or otherwise.

Comment: That's correct, it is related to dir(), I just observed while testing dir().